# Is Swing Explorer for Eclipse (Luna) still relevant?

Tags: eclipse, swing

There are a few other posts related to Swing Explorer but they are old and the links either no longer work or take you to some sketchy web site.

Doing a Google search results in the same for Swing Explorer.

Is the Swing Explorer plugin for Eclipse still relevant or is there a new tool?

Is there a valid download site for Swing Explorer or the latest tool being used (and any associated documentation)?